# How can I attach a function to a click event and have that check a control state before being called?

Tags: jquery

I assign the following function to my links after the document is ready:

```
$('.deleteLink')
  .click(function () { gridClick(this, 'Delete'); return false; });
```

On my screen I have a checkbox:

```
<input id="htmlEdit" type="checkbox" style="float: left"/>
```

How can I make it so that the gridClick function is called with a parameter of true or false depending on if the check box has been checked or not?

I am not sure how to do  this as it seems to me that the gridClick function will be attached to the links when the document is ready but then after that I can go in and check or uncheck the checkbox.

If the function is already attached then how can it at the time of clicking the link 
check if the checkbox is checked or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is this something you are looking for. I edited your code to pass another argument to gridClick function. The new argument passes true or false based on whether checkbox is checked or not.

```
    $('.deleteLink').click(function () {
       var isChecked = $('input[type="checkbox"]').is(":checked");

       gridClick(this, 'Delete', isChecked); return false;
    });
    function gridClick(isClick, isdelete, isChecked){
        alert(isChecked)
    }
```

The sample html code I used is as below

```
<a href="#" class="deleteLink">Click</a>
<input id="htmlEdit" type="checkbox" style="float: left"/> ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: Thanks so much. What's the significance of the (e) after your function? I had () and I'm not sure what the (e) does.

Comment: @Jessica. it is eventObject. jquery passes eventObject as an argument to click function. EventObject has all information about the event it is associated with. if you do a simple console.log(e), you want find lot of information about the event, in your case, about click event. You can find more information here http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/. It is not required to pass the eventObject. I removed it in the code above

Answer (score 0):

**Check this it would give you the result**

//your checkbox should be like this

```
<input id="htmlEdit" type="checkbox" style="float: left" />
```

//jquery

```
$('document').ready(function(){
                        $('#htmlEdit').click(function () { gridClick(this.value,'Delete'); return false; });
                   });

                   function gridClick(data,state)
                   {

                       if(state =='Delete')
                       {
                            confirm('Are you sure you want to delete'+data);
                       }    
                   }
```

Comment: .The OP has links with class of 'deleteLink'.